# How to display wait cursor when focusing on a RTB in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, cursor

So what is happening right now is the following. When I am focusing on a rich text box in my WPF application, I can't seem to change the cursor from a Carat (or what ever the 'I' text selection cursor is).

This is a problem, because when the user hits Ctrl+S, I want the program to save, and I want to display the **Cursor.Wait** cursor. This works if I am focusing on any other control (Treeview, stackPanel, Menu), everything except the RTB.

Is it just built this way with no way around it?

Answer (score 0):

[FrameworkElement.ForceCursor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.forcecursor.aspx) set to `True` will override the cursor preferences established by child elements:

```
<StackPanel ForceCursor="True" Cursor="Wait">
    <RichTextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

Now `RichTextBox` will show `StackPanel` cursor.